# Matlab: How to implement an equation for a dynamical system and time series

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, time-series, nonlinear-functions

I am having difficulty in understanding a technique for clustering and segmentation of biomedical images using the concept of time series. The paper on which the Question is based is : *M. Lacomi et. al, Mammographic images segmentation based on
chaotic map clustering algorithm*  [download link](http://bmcmedimaging.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2342-14-12).

There are a set of **N** points {**r**_i} in a D dimensional space. A real variable **x**_i in [0,1] is asigned to each point and the pair wise interactions **J**_ij = exp[-(**r**_i - **r**_j)^2 / 2a^2] where a is the local length scale. The time evolution of the system is given by [image: EQuation]

The function `f` has a close resemblance to the activation function in neural network. 
It is the [logistic map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map) which is a unimodal and univariate discrete in time non-linear dynamical system.
I am looking for a faster and efficient (vectorized) way to apply Eq(1) when 
N = 1 million points that are features of images . t spans from 1 to 10 time evolutions. The way I did but unsure if the code is proper. I am randomnly generating a matrix R of dimension D = 50 and containing 100 data points.

```
N = 100;
D = 50;
T  =10;
R = rand(N,D);
x = zeros(N,T);
y(1) = rand();
for i = 1:N   %// for loop indicating the number of sample points
    y(i+1) = 1-2*y(i)^2; %/* the iterations of the map f */
    r_1(i) = R(i,:);
    r_2(i) = R(i+1,:);
    sum_j = 0.0;
    for t = 1:T
        x(i,:)= y;
        a = var(r(i));
        J = {exp(-(r_1(i) - r_2(i+1))^2)}/2a;
        sum_j = sum_j+J*(1-2*x(i+1,t)));
        x(i,t) =  (1/c(i))*(sum_j);
    end
end
```

A small implementation using matrix where each row is the data element and columns are the the dimensions will be very helpful in order to expand the code for multi dimensional images. I am having a tough time to code Eq(1).

Comment: Your code is obviously not ok, it does not even run without errors. You should check it again and make sure you posted the right version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I can give an easy final answer on this one, but I can definitely give you a few helpful tips:

1. Calculate the matrix `J` once in advance. The information in it is static, so you don't want to recalculate. Idem ditto with `Ci`.
2. The part `sum(Jij*yj)` is actually the product of a matrix with a vector. This can be done fastest with linear algebra, i.e. `J*y`.
3. Vectorize the function `f`: instead of doing f(x_i) for each element separately, do f(x) for all at once. E.g. `f(x) = 1-2*x.^2` with `.^` instead of `^` performs the power operator on each element of x.
4. You probably want to put the time-iteration as the outer loop. This is the only sequential calculation you need to do. All the rest, you want to do as much as possible simultaneously (~ parallel) using vectorization and linear algebra.

This should give you a good starting point. If there is other stuff that needs help afterwards, update your question or give a comment. At this point, it's all I can do. Partly, because your code sample isn't very clear/descriptive. Maybe you want to add comments if there are particular reasons for how it is now.

Good luck!

### EDIT:

Code sample:

```
% Jmod is a modification of the matrix J:
%    1. Jmod(i,j) = J(i,j)/C(i) ==> the division by Ci is included
%    2. Jmod(i,i) = 0 ==> the diagonal elements are zero such that the term
%       for i=j is not included in the sum.

% Memory allocation
x = zeros(N,T+1); 
y = zeros(N,T+1);

% Initialization with your choice of x0
x(:,1) = x0;

% Time iterations
for t=1:T 
    y(:,t) = 1 - 2*x(:,t).^2;
    x(:,t+1) = Jmod*y(:,t);         
end
```

You don't really need both vectors `x` and `y`, but I have used them in this sample for clarity.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The part that is still unclear is Eq(1) where the output is x_i at t+1 is obtained from the input   x_j at t. How do I apply the function / map f to do this calculation. If you could provide the code for Eq(1) and the steps that you have outlined using a small array then I can build and expand from there. Thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: Thank you for your edit. One last Question, if you can kindly clarify. Eq(1) has x_j in the right hand side and the other data point x_i depends  on iteration of x_j at time t. i and j are two separate data points. In the code, should we be applying the variable x separately to pairs of data points insteadof doing x(:,t+1)?Should there be a loop for i and j or is the code performing the same thing?

Comment: Then all of the N data samples are initialized by the same scalar x0. Should the initialization be different for each x? i.e., there should be a vector of initial values x0, one for each data sample?

Comment: 1) A matrix-vector product does the following in general (with vectors x,y and matrix A): `y = Ax` --> `y_j = sum_i A_ij x_i`. So, by writing Eq. 1 using a matrix-vector product takes care of the influence of all elements of x(t) on x(t+1).

Comment: 2) According to your question, x is a vector with length N, so it contains N elements. By setting `x(:,1) = x0`, where x0 is the vector of length N containing the initial state of x(t), all N values of x(t) are initialized.

Comment: Hi again. Sorry to sound noisy. I am building up the program from your answer and there is a last confusion. Could you please clear that? You said in the comment that x0 is a vector of initial conditions, so there will be N different scalars each representing an initial condition. Is my understanding correct? Thank you for your continued help.